# Error executing the react-native-init command

Tags: node.js, macos, react-native, npm

I'm trying to create a React Native project on MacOs through Terminal. I type the following commands in Terminal:

```
> cd Desktop
> mkdir curso-react
> cd curso-react/
> react-native init exercicios
```

After running the `react-native init` command the following permission error is displayed for me:

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permission error in the folder was corrected with the `sudo` command before the `react-native` command, like this:

```
> sudo react-native init exercicios
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems permission for `.npm` folder is not right run this command to fix this issue:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```